# How to use IDA pro to find ALL strings in an exe file?

Tags: ida, strings

I've been using IDA for some time and most of the time I can find the strings I am looking for in the String panel.
In one of the recent exe files I was working on, many string are missing, or not shown in IDA.
Sure, not all string are always visible in an exe files, some may reside outside but when I load the same exe file into [this site](https://suip.biz/?act=rabin2) for searching all strings it found all the missing string not visible in IDA.

My question is how to make IDA show ALL the strings?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I did not induce teh resources when importing the .exe file.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely, the problem is that there are different encodings in one exe file.
However, you can customize the display of the encodings you need at any time.

[image]